# How to change every items in list to variables in dictionary?(python)

Tags: python, function, dictionary

```
def mul(dict(x)):
  for y in y.values():
    print(y, x[y])

mul(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,F=5)
```

I want to get the result as

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
F 5
```

I have to use dictionary, but I want to use only one variable, x, in multiplication function. How can I use it in 'mul' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `**` to pack keyword arguments into a `dict`:

```
def mul(**kwargs):
    for y in kwargs:
        print(y, kwargs[y])

mul(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,F=5)
```

Output:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
F 5
```